# how to access freenet on a remote machine from android

Tags: linux, android, virtualization, remote-server, freenet

The goal is to use freenet on non-rooted android devices.

It is far out of my capabilities to actually port Freenet to android, but I am attempting to use and provide a functioning solution for android.

I was able to use "gnuroot debian" to install java and freenet on my device via command line. 
w3m browser works for basic functions but it's not much good without images and video support.

Xterm seems to use too many resources and crashes / freezes the device.

The most promising solution seems to be to "Allow Freenet Remote HTTP Connections" as described here. https://old-wiki.freenetproject.org/InFrequentlyAskedQuestions

but I do not understand how to connect. what Ip would my android device have  and what ip would my virtual debian installation have. How would i make my regular android browser (firefox) access 127.0.0.1:8888 on the virtual machine? Is this method even possible?

How would you go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freenet works best on a machine that has good internet connectivity and can stay online as often and as long as possible. Mobile phones usually satisfy none of these conditions, and are often not particularly suitable to run Freenet on (although it is possible, as you have experienced).

I would recommend running Freenet on an always-online PC, and then use your Android device to browse Freenet using that installation. The safest way to go about this is by SSH port forwarding: SSH client apps like ConnectBot allow you to forward a local port to a remote destination.
An easier way is to configure Freenet to bind to the wildcard address 0.0.0.0 (relevant setting: *fproxy.bindTo*), and then limit access to only your phone or your local network by their IPs (relevant settings: *fproxy.allowedHosts* and *fproxy.allowedHostsFullAccess*).

If you insist on running Freenet on the same Android device as you'd like to browse Freenet with, your approach with GNURoot and Debian should work out of the box (that is, after installing a Java 7 or later, installing Freenet, and starting Freenet). Android apps and the GNURoot Debian share the same loopback interface: they can communicate over the 127.0.0.1 IP address as usual. As such, just start Freenet and point your browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8888`. If that doesn't work, consult wrapper.log and/or logs/freenet-latest.log in the Freenet installation directory for more information on what is happening.

Comment: Thank you! As you said there was no extra modification required. firefox can access http://127.0.0.1:8888 just fine. Very nice. now I am only having some issues with freenet using too much cpu and crashing the phone after a few minutes. "cpulimit" works fine on ubuntu, but on gnuroot debian it makes no changes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819701/how-to-limit-proccess-cpu-usage-on-gnuroot-for-android